# Выбор поля из парсера API

Tags: android, c#, json, xamarin

Добрый день

Пишу приложения под Андроид, столкнулся с проблемой парсинга API через JSON.

Пишу в Xamarin на С#

имеется сам API

```html
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 4238
            [post_author] => 7
            [post_date] => 2015-09-08 12:29:11
            [post_date_gmt] => 2015-09-08 08:29:11
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Ямато
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => open
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => yamato
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2015-09-08 12:29:11
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-09-08 08:29:11
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://new.murakami.ua/shop/yamato/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => product
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [img_url] => 
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 99.00
            [weight] => 
            [energy] => 
            [sku] => 480
            [category] => 182
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 4237
            [post_author] => 7
            [post_date] => 2015-09-08 12:29:11
            [post_date_gmt] => 2015-09-08 08:29:11
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Фудзіяма
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => fudziyama
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2015-09-10 19:45:41
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-09-10 15:45:41
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://new.murakami.ua/shop/fudziyama/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => product
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [img_url] => 
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 99.00
            [weight] => 
            [energy] => 230
            [sku] => 471
            [category] => 182
        )
```

Мне нужно выбирать товар по [sku], по номеру элемента нельзя, поскольку он может меняться при добавлении товаров.

Что было реализовано:

Cобственно сама строка с ссылкой где находится API

```
 string url2 = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
        JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url2);
```

Сам парсер который получает полный список товаров.

```
private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url2)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url2));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));

                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());


                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc;
            }
```

Если выбирать по элементу массива то код будет подобный

```
  private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue json)
    {


        //ImageButton product = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.vugor);
        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.weight);
        JsonValue firstitem = json[31];
        //Console.Out.WriteLine(firstitem["post_title"].ToString());
        productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
        price.Text = firstitem["price"] + " грн";
        weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";
```

Ка сделать чтобы выборка происходила по [sku]?

Answer (score 1):

1)Скопируйте Json по ссылке и воспользуйтесь специальной вставкой в VS для автоматического формирования класса.

2)Воспользуйтесь Newtonsoft Json для десериализации данных. Судя по жсону по ссылке, там коллекция объектов. На сколько я помню, на Xamarin эта библиотека работает корректно.

3)Воспользуйтесь Linq для выборки нужного поля.

Например:

```
var listOfObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjectClass>>(jsonString);
var first = listOfObjects.FirstOfDefaut(x=> x.Sku == 123);
```